# How to represent this in OO design

Tags: oop

```
A type has many subtypes.

A subtype is also a type.
```

How to represent these two statements in Object oriented design?

```
Class AbstractType{
}

Class Type extends AbstractType{
      List<Subtype> subtypes
}

Class Subtype extends Type{

}
```

Comment: What are your ideas? Share those first please.

Comment: literally a 5 second online search could give you some useful information.

Comment: I have pretty much no idea what you are asking. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the idea of subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism.  [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). Exactly how to do it depends on the language/oop model.